# How to use templatesImport in build.sbt with Playframework 2.2.x

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have to import some reusable blocks in all my templates.

I have defined a block in `app\views\blocks\header.scala.html`, to include the block in all my templates (as described [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTemplates)) I have included in build.sbt this line:

```
templatesImport += "views.html.blocks._"
```

but I have this compilation error:

```
[error] E:\workspace\play2test\app\views\admin\main.scala.html:13: not found: value header
[error]         @header()
[error]          ^
```

the block is not imported, what I have to change?

note that if I import the block in the template with `@import blocks._` it works.

Comment: What imports are added in the compiled views? if the views.html.blocks isn't there, than the templatesImport may not work properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem: In build.sbt I have to move the line `templatesImport += "views.html.blocks._"` after the line `play.Project.playJavaSettings`.

This is due to the fact that `playJavaSettings` initializes the variable `templatesImport` with the defaults imports.