# TwirlKeys.templateImports with Play not being resolved in IntelliJ IDEA template files

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I have the template imports set to import dependencies necessary for the templates, but none of the dependencies are resolved with IntelliJ.

Template Imports:
[image: Template imports]

Template file:
[image: Template file]

Here is my entire Build.scala:

```
import play.sbt.PlayImport._
import play.sbt.PlayScala
import play.sbt.routes.RoutesKeys._
import play.twirl.sbt.Import.TwirlKeys
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

object Build extends Build {
    lazy val core = Project(id = "core", base = file(".")).settings(
    name := "core",
    version := "0.1",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.6",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        jdbc,
        cache,
        ws,
        filters,
        specs2 % Test,
        "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.4.0",
        "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27",
        "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.3.2",
        "com.googlecode.xmemcached" % "xmemcached" % "2.0.0",
        "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3" % "1.10.49",
        "io.argonaut" %% "argonaut" % "6.0.4",
        "com.sksamuel.scrimage" %% "scrimage-core" % "2.1.2",
        "javax.mail" % "mail" % "1.4.7",
        "io.fastjson" % "boon" % "0.31",
        "net.debasishg" %% "redisclient" % "2.13",
        "com.mohiva" %% "play-html-compressor" % "0.5.0" exclude("rhino", "js"),
        "com.yahoo.platform.yui" % "yuicompressor" % "2.4.7" exclude("rhino", "js"),
        "com.github.jreddit" % "jreddit" % "1.0.2",
        "com.notnoop.apns" % "apns" % "1.0.0.Beta6",
        "com.sksamuel.scrimage" %% "scrimage-canvas" % "1.4.2"
    ),
    resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases",
    doc in Compile <<= target.map(_ / "none"),
    routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator,
    TwirlKeys.templateImports += "core.data.db.models._",
    unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+=  baseDirectory ( _ /"target/web/public/test" )
    ).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
}
```

I have verified that all the package routes are correct. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you attach whole build.sbt ? Maybe you override variable `Twirlkeys.templateImports` later like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118797/how-to-use-templatesimport-in-build-sbt-with-playframework-2-2-x

Comment: Do you have auto import enabled for SBT (Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > SBT - there is a checkbox)? If yes, have you tried to invalidate caches? (File > Invalidate Caches / Restart)

Comment: @mgosk I have edited the question. The weird thing is that I can run the server fine, so the importing is happening, just not in IntelliJ

Comment: @lpiepiora Yes I have tried both of those things.

Comment: Are you using intellij IDEA Ultimate or community?

Comment: Ok @Wiz, it is strange, have you tried to create a vanilla project following https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/getting-started-with-play-2-x.html ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get intellij IDEA to help developing templates, you need Intellij IDEA Ultimate with the latest Scala plugin updated. 
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/

Also make sure you enable Play 2 compiler in the settings
[image]

It should work without any special configuration in your build.sbt

As a reference you can create a new Play2 project and see the templates properly working
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/getting-started-with-play-2-x.html

With this setup working you can use TwirlKeys.templateImports to avoid adding the import to all your templates.