# How to use templatesImport in build.sbt with Playframework 2.5.x

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.5

I have the same issue raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118797/how-to-use-templatesimport-in-build-sbt-with-playframework-2-2-x).  I'm using Play 2.5.10, Scala 2.11.7 and sbt 0.13.11

I'd like to import common packages in every template.

I get a build error when I use the following in my build.sbt:

```
templatesImport ++= Seq(
    "helper._",
    "play.api._"
)
```

Build error:

```
build.sbt: error: not found: value templatesImport
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates#import-statements):

Changed it to:

```
TwirlKeys.templateImports ++= Seq(
  "helper._",
  "play.api._"
)
```